# Database Connection not Working as Include File

Tags: php, mysql, include

I want to move the my database connection info to an include file - normally, the database connects fine when I have it written out in the entire php header like this:

```
   <?php

        define('DB_LOCATION', 'x');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'x');
        define('DB_PASS', 'x');
        define('DB_NAME', 'x');

        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_LOCATION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error connecting to database');

        $error_message= "";

        $user_name = $_POST['user'];
        $user_password= $_POST['pass'];

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            ......
        }
```

Here, I moved this info to it's own file as an include file. It's saved as a (.php) file.

```
  <?php

        define('DB_LOCATION', 'x');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'x');
        define('DB_PASS', 'x');
        define('DB_NAME', 'x');

        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_LOCATION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error connecting to database');


    ?>
```

Now, I replaced database connection with the include file mentioned above. Both the script and the include file are in the same directory/folder. However when I go to my page with the require_once include in the header, the page is blank. I'm not getting a database error which means it is connecting, but I am not seeing my content either.

Could it be that that the location is not properly specified? Both are under file /LESSON. I also tried using @require_once and it did not help. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

require_once("/LESSON5/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php");

?>

<?php 

    session_start();

    $error_message= "";

    $user_name = "";

    ......
?>
```

Comment: Is the file really in a root-level directory called `LESSON5`? That's root on the server itself, not where the webserver looks for files.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks for your reply. What do you recommend? I'm new to creating/organizing file structures. I'd like to know the best way to do this.

Comment: As the answer states, you can just use a local path, if it's in the same directory. You can also add in an absolute path `('/var/html/www/whatever.php')` - there's no one best way to organise these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your both files are in same directory then there is no need to give the name of directory just give the name of the file.

In your case use

```
require_once("Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php");
```

and if you use @ in front of your function call to suppress all error messages.
Thats why you are getting blank page

Comment: thanks. that worked. I previously had the file in a separate folder /inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php but it still did not connect.

Comment: you have to do like this `require_once("../inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php");`

Comment: `../` will let you come out from the current directory and then you can go to the other directory.